# data is not added in arraylist while using asynctask

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development.I am developing a application which gets data from the server. It works fine but lags device screen as it is working in UI thread .So i have used asynctask to get that data and display it in recyclerview but its not showing the data.Please help me thanks:)

code:-in oncreateView()

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_news, container, false);
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        dlist=new ArrayList<>();
        new DataLoader().execute();
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.newsrecycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerAdapter=new DisplayRecyclerAdapter(list,dlist,getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter );
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return view;
}
```

and My Async task class

```
  public class DataLoader extends AsyncTask{
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
       pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       pDialog.setCancelable(false);
       pDialog.show();
   }

   @Override
   protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
       myConnection=new MyConnection();
       connection=myConnection.DatabaseConncetion1();
       list.clear();
       dlist.clear();
       try {
           statement = connection.createStatement();
           resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select title,[desc] from events order by E_ID  desc;");
           while (resultSet.next()) {
               list.add(resultSet.getString("title"));
               dlist.add(resultSet.getString("desc"));
           }

       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
       @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
       super.onPostExecute(o);
       pDialog.dismiss();
            }
```

}

```
  @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new DataLoader().execute();
}
```

Comment: i just want to get data from mssql database.please tell me how i can do it .Thanks

Comment: you are adding value to list in doInBg, so on PostExecute() , just  call this ,adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ,

Comment: thanks @notTdar its working but progress dialog is not dismissing

Comment: recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not needed after setting adapter. NotifyDataSetChanged tells adapter that something has been changed. But for the first time nothing is changed, data is same as you set it. But when you add data list.add(resultSet.getString("title")); dlist.add(resultSet.getString("desc")); call that method to let adapter actually know something has been updated. You can remove notifyDataSetChanged from above.

Comment: if(pDialog!= null &&pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }, and remove notifyDataSetChanged() from onCreate since have added nothing to list, use only ,when you have new data/or some changes

Comment: ok brother thanks..I will do this

Answer (score 1):

setDialogCancelable(true);

dont use adapter.notifidatasetchanged(); in the first TIme

Answer (score 0):

Remove `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onCreateView()`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_news, container, false);
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        dlist=new ArrayList<>();
        new DataLoader().execute();
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.newsrecycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerAdapter=new DisplayRecyclerAdapter(list,dlist,getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter );
        //recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); not required

    return view;
}
```

Notify the adapter that data has changed after `AsyncTask` finish executing. Just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()` for this

```
 @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
       super.onPostExecute(o);
       pDialog.dismiss();
       recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```